# How to sort out the array that only consisted alphabet?

Tags: java

There are 2 arrays. **code[] and text[]**

```
code[0] = 0, text[0] = "Monkey333banana" // has numbers in text
code[1] = 100, text[1] = "Dog"
code[2] = 200, text[2] = "Cat117" // has numbers in text
code[3] = 300, text[3] = "Pig"
```

I want pick up the array in text[] **consisted only alphabet**. **No numbers.**

```
code[1] = 100, text[1] = "Dog"
code[3] = 300, text[3] = "Pig"
```

And I want to save another new array.

```
newCode[0] = 100, text[0] = "Dog"
newCode[1] = 300, newText[1] = "Pig"
```

Example code :

```
String[] code = new String[4];
int[] text = new int[4];

code[0] = 0;
code[1] = 100;
code[2] = 200;
code[3] = 300;

text[0] = "Monkey333banana";
text[1] = "Dog";
text[2] = "Cat117";
text[3] = "Pig";

// *** MAGIC **** //
// *** MAGIC **** //
// *** MAGIC **** //

for (int i=0; i<(proper size); i++)
System.out.println(newCode[i]+" : "+newText[i]);
```

result :

- 100 : Dog;
- 300 : Pig;

How can I do this magic? Please help me. Thank you!

Sorry ... for act imprudently, I wrote `magic` maybe people think this is bad, sorry...

Comment: Use a loop to separate them. You should use a `class` to group the text and the code though.

Comment: You introduce the `code` array, but I don't see you using it for anything anywhere. Do you mean the output should be "100: Dog, 300: Pig"?

Comment: @kba Sorry ! My mistake. I editted. Thank you!

Comment: Write a loop.  You do know how to write a loop, right?  Then inspect each element.  You may have to write another loop to inspect each letter of your word to see if it's an alphabetic character or not.

Comment: Sorry for every people, I think my writing was rude... Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps provided:

- size of both the arrays are same...

  ```
  public static void main (String[] args) {

      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // store code[] value
      ArrayList<String> listS = new ArrayList<String>(); // store string w/o numbers

      int code[] = {0, 100, 200, 300}; //example
      String text[] = {"M12", "Dog", "117Cat", "Pig"}; //example

      for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

          if (! text[i].matches(".*\\d+.*")) { // VERY IMP REGEX TO TEST IF STRING CONTAINS ANY NUMBER
              list.add(i); // or add(code[i]);
              listS.add(text[i]);
          }
      }

      int newCode[] = new int[list.size()];
      int idx = 0;
      for (int x : list) {
          newCode[idx++] = x;
      }

      String newText[] = listS.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

      for (int i=0; i < newCode.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(newCode[i] + " : " + newText[i]);
      }
  }
  ```
- Instead of writing `magic` put some effort/research before posting question

Comment: Thank you... I think that is more clear than write my dirty code... Sorry... It works. Thank you and have a fantastic christmas.

Comment: The result of `newCode` is not value of code, it is index number... I edited my writing, it was my mistake please check it thank you.

Comment: plz check my comment in for loop

Comment: Sorry. I'm not good at english so I couldn't understand. now I fixed it. Thank you so much. ( I love india - paharganj )

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] newText = new String[4];
    int[] newCode = new int[4];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<text.length;++i){
        if(text[i].matches("\\A[a-zA-Z]+\\z")){
            newCode[j]=code[i];
            newText[j++]=text[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
        System.out.println(newCode[i]+" : "+newText[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That magic:

```
for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++)
    textvalid[i]=true;    //saying that all the strings are valid. We will mark them as unvalid later
k=0;    //a counter
for(int i=0;i<text.length;i++) {    //every string in the array
    for(int j=0, char[] text1 = text.toCharArray();j<text1.length;j++)      //every character in the string. text1 is the char[] equivallent of text[i]
        if(text1[j]<'A' || (text1[j] >'Z' && text1[j]<'a') || text1[j] <='z') //if it is not a capital letter nor a lowercase one
            textvalid[i] = false; //mark it as a npn-valid string
    if(textvalid[i]==true){    //if it is valid, add it to the newtext array
        newText[k++] = text[i];
        newCode[k] = code[i];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

here i am posting a hint further it is your duty to do it yourself

```
for(char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++){
System.out.println(i+" ");
}
```